# How to deploy django server into production environment without a full source code?

Tags: django, deployment, mod-wsgi, egg

I am still a newbie to Python and Django. I am developing a application using Django which will eventually go to the production server. It's a customized web application for the client. After doing some research, I found out `Apache with mod_wsgi` is the best option for `Django` deployment. I just have to copy and paste the code into the production server and the application is accessible. But what if I don't want to give the whole source code and give only the executable application to the client`(P.S client wants to deploy the application to their own server)`. Is something like this possible in `Python/Django`?

Comment: You're question topic doesn't correlate with the question being asked. To answer the topic question: No, an `.egg` is the python equivalent of a `.jar`.

Answer (score 2):

You could only give them the .pyc files corresponding to your source code files. That will make it slightly harder for them to look at your source code. However, it's a very limited measure (i.e. they can still recover some of the structure from your source code), and it's probably a bad idea.

Comment: At least the WSGI script file has to be provided as source code as mod_wsgi will not load a WSGI script file from a .pyc file. The .pyc files would also need to be the same version as the Python installation being used. Agree that trying to hide any secrets by using .pyc files is silly.